# avconv and ffmpeg - drawtext filter text_w evaluates as 0 in Ubuntu Precise

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ffmpeg, libav

I'm attempting to draw text onto a video using either the avconv or ffmpeg commands. When specifying x= for where on the final video to place the text, the 'text_w' value is evaluating to 0, rather than the width of the rendered text as it should.

- I'm using Ubuntu 12.04
- I've got avconv version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
- and ffmpeg version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Example command:

```
avconv -i test.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf':text='test text':x=text_w:y=50:fontsize=24:fontcolor=black" texted.mov
```

This command causes the text to be printed as if x were set to 0.

What I'd really like to be able to do is center the text horizontally using something like this:

```
avconv -i test.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf':text='test text':x=(main_w-text_w)/2:y=50:fontsize=24:fontcolor=black" texted.mov
```

Using ffmpeg for to attempt the same ends with the same result

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf':text='test text':x=(main_w-text_w)/2:y=50:fontsize=24:fontcolor=black" texted.mov
```

Comment: Not an expert on the filters, but have you tried in the latest version? It's at least at 0.11 now.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The command you wrote: `avconv -i test.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf':text='test text':x=(main_w-text_w)/2:y=50:fontsize=24:fontcolor=black" texted.mov` works fine for me.

Comment: abhshkdz: The command does not error for me, but it does fail to center the text. The calculated x location is the same as if 'text_w' were replaced with 0. Is the text centered properly in your output video? Sounds like this could be a bug on this version.

Comment: Works for me using ffmpeg from FFmpeg (and not the fork that Ubuntu now uses): https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide.

Comment: Is anyone else able to confirm the bad behavior on the libav fork that Ubuntu uses? If this is recreatable I'd like to file a bug report.